# Site is getting requests for strange query strings

Tags: php, httprequest

I was evaluating the logs for a website I help run and I noticed a repeating pattern of strange requests. The requests are all very similar, and from different IP addresses (possibly a bot net?). I am curious if anybody understands what the point of such a bizarre request is and if there is a security concern:

```
%5BPLM=0%5D+GET+http://example.org/+%5B0,7309,7252%5D+-%3E+%5BN%5D+POST+http://example.org/+%5B0,0,7329%5D
```

which decodes to:

```
[PLM=0] GET http://example.org/ [0,7309,7252] -> [N] POST http://example.org/ [0,0,7329]
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything you dont recognize can be construed as a security concern and if its happening at any significant volume than I would consider it a threat and start finding a way to filter them out via some access rules / firewall, etc

Comment: I did start looking for `[PLM=` and just `die()` to prevent whatever they are trying to do, but it has still peaked my curiosity.