# Getting requests containing [PLM=0][N]

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

I recently noticed that I've been getting some strange looking requests which after decoding look like

```
target_url?id=17 [PLM=0][N] GET target_url?id=17 [0,14770,13801] -> [N] POST target_url?id=17 [R=302][8880,0,522]
```

I know there is an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586537/site-is-getting-requests-for-strange-query-strings) concerning that subject, but there is no actual answer so I posted my own, in case there may be some newer member who knows what's going on.

The requests I mentioned do not seem to have any effect as they cause the error page to be displayed. I am however curious to know what they might have been capable of.

target_url only refers to pages where someone posts to the forum. The website uses ASP.NET. The numbers contained in brackets (0,14770,13801 etc) seem to be the same in every request made so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also getting this on a Drupal. It's similar to yours, however they are trying to skoot around captcha by putting this at the end of the request: `-> [N] GET http:/www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript/` Just FYI the IP it came from is `171.212.226.46`

Answer (score 0):

I see things more or less similar on sereval websites and I think it is a code for passing by your captcha in the form you have on the page id=17. My guess would be that :

- `GET target_url?id=17 [0,14770,13801]` = Get the captcha at the position [0,14770,13801] on the page, where the captcha image or computation or else has been detected ;
- `POST target_url?id=17 [R=302][8880,0,522]` = still on the same page, put it back in the field at the position [8880,0,522]. `[R=302]` is possibly an error redirect management in case it is wrong.

Comment: Sounds nice, however in my case the pages I get these requests contain no captcha. In fact since I posted the question, I've been getting requests in new pages that have nothing to do with forum posting and contain no captcha as well. Well, the fact that I get such requests in no-captcha-pages, does not indicate that they were definitely made to be used on such random pages. Is there a reference concerning your answer where more info can be found? As an update to my original question the new requests I've been getting, are missing the "[N]" part eg target_url?id=17 [PLM=0] GET target_url...